# Sum group by foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sum quantity in table B and group by an id based on the date time it was created and connect with the id of table A.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
  Id int,
  Name varchar(50),
  Type varchar(10),
  ForeignKeyId int,
  created_at datetime
);

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
  Id int,
  Qunatity decimal(10,2),
  TableA_id int,
  created_at datetime,
);
```

I made I query like this but it doesn't work

```
    SELECT a.*,t1.quantity from TableA a 
    inner join 
    (
     Select a.id as id, sum(b.quantity) as quantity from TableA a   
     inner join TableB b on b.TableA_Id = a.Id
     where a.created_at between '2020-07-28' and IF('2020-07-28' > a.created_at, '2020-07- 
    28', a.created_at)
    group by a.foreignKeyId
   ) t1 on t1.id = a.id
```

It groups by foreign key ID so if there are only 4 foreign key ids and 100 rows in TableA it only shows 4 rows and it groups the sum for all rows in Table A. But the desired output is like this:

For every row in Table A to add the sum of the quantity between the static date and the date that the row was created.

```
   -----------------------------------------------------
   |  Id     | name |foreingKeyID |  quantity  |  sum  |
   -----------------------------------------------------
   | 1       |name1 |1            | 30         |  30   |
   | 2       |name2 |2            | 10         |  10   |
   | 3       |name3 |2            | 10         |  20   |
    ----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Add your sample data too.

Comment: Your query has very little to do with the question you seem to be asking.

Answer (score 1):

> For every row in Table A to add the sum of the quantity between the static date and the date that the row was created.

You can use `join` and `group by`.  Assuming that `TableA(id)` is the primary key, then this should do what you want:

```
select a.*, sum(b.quantity)
from TableA a left join
     TableB b
     on b.TableA_Id = a.Id and
        b.created_at >= '2020-07-28' and
        b.created_at <= a.created_at
group by a.id;
```